# how to create dynamic table using .rml report in odoo?

Tags: python, openerp-7, rml

i have one module feedback_form their i have few fields . now i am able to get all values in report . but i have two fields those should come in table format . one record may have 2 values in both fields . other record may have 4 values in both fields .
So i should get dynamic way of  row creation

```
'insp_msr1' : fields.many2many('results.measure','results_measure_rel','super_id','results_measure_id','Result',),
'insp_rslt' : fields.one2many('feedback.tree','insp_rsltts','Inspection Result',),
```

how to get this two fields in .RML report with table format
[[repeatIn(o.insp_rslt,'l', 'tr') ]][[([ tc.valuess or '' for tc in o.insp_rslt ]) ]]

have tried with it but m not able to make in the form of table

Comment: please reply any one

Comment: RML report  is deprecated in Odoo it is the part of OpenERP 7.0 please  edit your Question Odoo to OpenERP 7.0 or previous version

Answer (score 1):

you have to add section for that like this:

```
<section>
  <para>[[repeatIn(o.insp_rslt,'line')]]</para>
  <blockTable colWidths="180.0" >
    <tr>
      <td>
        <para>[[ format(line.name) ]] </para>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </blockTable>
</section>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072026/how-to-get-field-values-in-rml-report-in-odoo/32072645?noredirect=1#comment52069570_32072645 this is link where i have code